# Reconfigure Razer Orbweaver without Synapse 2.0

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, macros, autohotkey, razer-keyboard, razer-synapse

Is there a way how one can remap the Orbweaver's buttons to other keyboard functions, or even macros without using the Razer Synapse 2.0 Software, if the device, in this case the Orbweaver, is not supported by the Synapse 3.0 Software?

Not using Synapse 2.0 is the goal, as it has caused numerous Blue-Screens on Windows 10 over the last few weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using *AutoHotInterception*, as it allows the use of AutoHotkey Scripts, while distinguishing between multiple keyboards, as the Orbweaver acts like a Keyboard on its own.

## Installation

The AutoHotInterception GitHub Page is located at
https://github.com/evilC/AutoHotInterception

1. Download and install [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
2. Download the [Interception Driver](http://www.oblita.com/interception)
3. Download the latest [AutoHotInterception Relase](https://github.com/evilC/AutoHotInterception/releases)
4. Follow the instructions on the GitHub Page for a detailed installation of AutoHotInterception

## Finding the Orbweaver’s Device ID

1. Open the *Monitor.ahk* File inside the AutoHotInterception Folder
2. Check one device at a time by ticking it oﬀ, in order to ﬁnd the *VID* and *PID* of the
   Orbweaver, note them down for later. In my specific case, they are *0x1532* and *0x0113*, although this will probably vary for other users.

[image: Monitor]

## Creating the Script for the Macros

A complete working example of a *.ahk* script for the Orbweaver is provided here: It will simply
remap the Orbweaver’s *s* key to write a capital *O*. This can of course be expanded in functionality.

I have uploaded [a complete *.ahk* template](https://github.com/Galva101/OrbweaverAutoHotKey/blob/master/OrbweaverScript.ahk) for the Orbweaver on GitHub.

```
#Persistent ; (Interception hotkeys do not stop AHK from exiting, so use this)
#include Lib\AutoHotInterception.ahk

global AHI := new AutoHotInterception()

id := AHI.GetKeyboardId(0x1532, 0x0113)
cm1 := AHI.CreateContextManager(id)

#if cm1.IsActive
s::
send O
return
#if
```

Note, that the *VID* and *PID* of the Orbweaver have been inserted into the *GetKeyboardID*
Method, such that its *id* is returned for the Context Manager.

*Monitor.ahk* can also be used, to identify the names of the Orbweaver’s buttons, that can then be
placed into the conditional statements inside the autohotkey-script.